# Nullify VPC Config, if the account number is XXXXXX

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I have a below cloudformation code, i dont want to setup a VPC Configuration if the account is XXXXX

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: VPC function.
Mappings:
  "129921924252":
    "ap-southeast-1":
      Subnets:
        - "vpc-PrivateSubnetId1"
        - "vpc-PrivateSubnetId2"
Conditions:
  CheckAccount: {"Fn::Equals": [ !Ref AWS::AccountId, "123456780976"]}
Resources:
  Function:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: index.handler
      Role: arn:aws:iam::129921924252:role/service-role/ASG-Lambda-role-n27an6nj
      Code:
        ZipFile:
          Fn::Sub: |
            import json
            import boto3
            import os
            from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      Timeout: 5
      TracingConfig:
        Mode: Active
      VpcConfig:
        - Fn::If:
          - CheckAccount
          SecurityGroupIds:
            - sg-0305baf25b2dd4891
          SubnetIds:
            -
              Fn::ImportValue:
                Fn::Select: [0, Fn::FindInMap : [!Ref AWS::AccountId, !Ref AWS::Region, Subnets]]
            -
              Fn::ImportValue:
                Fn::Select: [1, Fn::FindInMap : [!Ref AWS::AccountId, !Ref AWS::Region, Subnets]]
        - !Ref AWS::NoValue
```

Im getting error when trying above code:

> Properties validation failed for resource Function with message: #/VpcConfig: expected type: JSONObject, found: JSONArray

Answer (score 3):

The syntax of your `Fn::If` statement seems to be incorrect. Have a look at the following example from the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html#intrinsic-function-reference-conditions-if):

```yaml
UpdatePolicy:
  AutoScalingRollingUpdate:
    !If 
      - RollingUpdates
      -
        MaxBatchSize: 2
        MinInstancesInService: 2
        PauseTime: PT0M30S
      - !Ref "AWS::NoValue"
```

So in your case that would be:

```yaml
      VpcConfig:
        - Fn::If:
          - CheckAccount
          - SecurityGroupIds:
              - sg-0305baf25b2dd4891
            SubnetIds:
              - Fn::ImportValue:
                  Fn::Select: [0, Fn::FindInMap : [!Ref AWS::AccountId, !Ref AWS::Region, Subnets]]
              - Fn::ImportValue:
                  Fn::Select: [1, Fn::FindInMap : [!Ref AWS::AccountId, !Ref AWS::Region, Subnets]]
        - !Ref AWS::NoValue
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @stijndepestel's answer above....here is a variation that uses YAML for the VPC configuration with parameter values:

```
      VpcConfig:
        Fn::If:
          - DeployIntoVPC
          - SecurityGroupIds:
              - !Ref MySecurityGroup
            SubnetIds: !Ref SubnetIds
          - !Ref AWS::NoValue
```